# PHP - distance between two locations, approach

Tags: php, geolocation, coordinates, distance

according to : http://sgowtham.net/ramblings/2009/08/04/php-calculating-distance-between-two-locations-given-their-gps-coordinates/

i'm gonna check distance between 2 given locations.

My dubt is which of these two approaches is "better" and why if?

Fisrt:

```
<?php

$earth_radius = 3960.00; # in miles
$lat_1 = "47.117828";
$lon_1 = "-88.545625";
$lat_2 = "47.122223";
$lon_2 = "-88.568781";
$delta_lat = $lat_2 - $lat_1 ;
$delta_lon = $lon_2 - $lon_1 ;

# Spherical Law of Cosines
function distance_slc($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
  global $earth_radius;
  global $delta_lat;
  global $delta_lon;
  $distance  = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($delta_lon)) ;
  $distance  = acos($distance);
  $distance  = rad2deg($distance);
  $distance  = $distance * 60 * 1.1515;
  $distance  = round($distance, 4);

  return $distance;
}

$slc_distance = distance_slc($lat_1, $lon_1, $lat_2, $lon_2);
?>
```

Second

```
<?php

$earth_radius = 3960.00; # in miles
$lat_1 = "47.117828";
$lon_1 = "-88.545625";
$lat_2 = "47.122223";
$lon_2 = "-88.568781";
$delta_lat = $lat_2 - $lat_1 ;
$delta_lon = $lon_2 - $lon_1 ;

function distance_haversine($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
  global $earth_radius;
  global $delta_lat;
  global $delta_lon;
  $alpha    = $delta_lat/2;
  $beta     = $delta_lon/2;
  $a        = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
  $c        = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
  $distance = 2*$earth_radius * $c;
  $distance = round($distance, 4);

  return $distance;
}

$hav_distance = distance_haversine($lat_1, $lon_1, $lat_2, $lon_2);
?>
```

Comment: i mean which i should use and why, which are differences between them ? Is one more accurated than other, which are value added of boths , which are bad and good things in use one or other :D .... definitely advantages/handicaps

Comment: @MarkBaker so having not idea if places are on same plane, the second seems generally more accurated right?

Comment: @MarkBaker you rock , can you right all you sad into an answer so , if no better answer i'll accept your for sure ;)

Comment: thanks a lot dude i encourage you to put all into an answer ;) really really thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Law of cosines calculation is based on a spherical earth; Haversine is a great circle calculation: given that the earth is an ellipse rather than a sphere, then Haversine is more accurate... although the Vincenty algorithm is a more accurate great circle calculation than Haversine, but slower to calculate. The cosines calculation is a fast approximation, reasonably accurate over short distances; Haversine is more accurate over longer distances because it more reasonably approximates the curvature of the earth, though it isn't particularly accurate for cross-polar great circles.

You can find a good explanations of the differences [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/why-is-law-of-cosines-more-preferable-than-haversine-when-calculating-distance-b)